# How to test unobtrusive jquery plugins using qunit and requirejs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, unit-testing, requirejs, qunit

I'm trying to test a `requirejs` module that implements a jquery widget. First two tests I'm trying to run are supposed to check unobtrusive behavior.

The problem is that for unobtrusive test to do his job, the html must be loaded before the `requirejs` module for the widget (at the end of the js file there is a line to look for a selector in html document to create the widget).

This is true for the first test execution as I'm loading the module dynamically inside the test but when the second test runs, the JavaScript module was already loaded so it doesn't create widget using the unobtrusive approach, causing the test to fail :)

How can I solve this situation?

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to judge whether this would work in *your* specific case since you describe your code in very generic terms but the first thing that comes to my mind would be to use [`require.undef()`](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#undef) to undefine your module between tests.